# Having trouble with speech to text in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio

```
import speech_recognition as sr

rec = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone as source:
    print('say something')
    audio = rec.listen(source)
    voice_data = rec.recognize_google(audio)
    print(voice_data)
```

This is my code which is shown in plenty of tutorials that I watched online, I installed SpeechRecognizer and pyAudio (using whl file, not with pip, I don't know if it makes a difference).

When I try to run it it gives me an error about something in the pydevd.py and at the end gives me:

> with sr.Microphone as source:
>
> AttributeError: **enter**

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by moving the statements not related to capturing the audio out of the with statement, this should work for you:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

rec = sr.Recognizer()

print('say something')
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = rec.listen(source)
    voice_data = rec.recognize_google(audio)

print(voice_data)
```